# Why is my program stopping when doing a seemingly infinite loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, floating-accuracy

This must be really obvious but I am currently doing a little tutorial that features this code snippet:

```
n=0
a=1
while a>0:
    n=n+1
    a=(1.0+2.0**(-n))-1.0
    print (n)
```

And I've tried to run it but it keeps getting stuck at n=53. Why? I just assumed that `while` would always be true ...

Comment: The obvious route to go is checking a before printing n (or all a's). The next step might be checking out fp-math.

Comment: @sascha but is it because a's value overflows the allowed? Because i checked it and i thought that would make sense... That is why i came here and not to fp-math

Comment: Nevermind, i was calculating it wrong, calculator has a funny way to make negative numbers i was not aware of

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you change the last line to `print(n, a)` you can see what's happening more clearly:

```
n = 0
a = 1
while a > 0:
    n = n + 1
    a = (1.0 + 2.0 ** (-n)) - 1.0
    print(n, a)
```

Output:

```
1 0.5
2 0.25
3 0.125
4 0.0625
# ...
50 8.881784197001252e-16
51 4.440892098500626e-16
52 2.220446049250313e-16
53 0.0
```

As you can see, `a` is half the size each time through the loop. Eventually, `2.0 ** (-n)` is so small that floating point math (which has limited precision) is unable to tell the difference between `1.0` and `1.0 + 2.0 ** (-n)`:

```
>>> 1.0 + 2.0 ** -51
1.0000000000000004
>>> 1.0 + 2.0 ** -52
1.0000000000000002
>>> 1.0 + 2.0 ** -53
1.0
```

… and when that happens, subtracting `1.0` from `1.0` gives you `0.0`, and the `while` loop terminates.

Comment: Thank you. I miss calculated a's value and actually thought it was causing an overflow. I understand now. You showed a really good way to check stuff like this in the future!